# TYPO3 - upload_max_filesize installation error

Tags: php, typo3

I get the following error during installation:

> PHP Maximum upload filesize too small PHP upload_max_filesize = 11 MB
>   TYPO3_CONF_VARS[BE][maxFileSize] = 10 MB
>
> Currently PHP determines the limits for uploaded file's sizes and not
>   TYPO3.  It is recommended that the value of upload_max_filesize is at
>   least equal to  the value of TYPO3_CONF_VARS[BE][maxFileSize].

I've changed the php.ini setting to 11MB, also `post_max_size=12`. How do I fix this error? Should I modify `TYPO3_CONF_VARS[BE][maxFileSize]` and set it to some lower value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**: The TYPO3 option `maxFileSize` was [removed in TYPO3 7.6](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/7.6/Breaking-71110-TYPO3-specificUploadLimitRemoved.html). It is now sufficient to change the PHP settings.

---

In **TYPO3 < 7.6** you have to specify the maxFileSize in Byte without any unit:

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['maxFileSize'] = '10240';
```

In your php.ini you have to set these settings:

```
post_max_size = 10M
upload_max_filesize = 10M
```

Comment: Also, in case that this won't fix the problem I've found an interesting comment about it but I didn't test it and I don't know, if it's still applicable (the post is from 2006). Link: http://lists.typo3.org/pipermail/typo3-english/2006-September/031314.html

Comment: The name of the variable is `maxFileSize` and not `maxUploadFileSize` that lead to a not working setting.

Comment: The TYPO3 setting $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['maxFileSize'] has been removed in TYPO3 7.6, see https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/7.6/Breaking-71110-TYPO3-specificUploadLimitRemoved.html

Comment: in Typo3 10.4.8?